# How were the scenes with Gazelle shot?

Tags: film-techniques, stunts, kingsman-the-secret-service

In *Kingsman: The Secret Service* Gazelle is disabled. I was surprised to discover that the actress playing the role (Sofia Boutella) is not. How were the scenes with her shot? Did she actually wear limbs, or had a stunt double, or it's just special effects?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They likely had Sofia Boutella wear special socks/coverings and added the assasin prosthetics later.

Effects like this have been achievable for quite some time now, as shown by the special effects shots of Gary Sinise as Lt. Dan in the film Forest Gump. Sinise wore blue socks during filming, and his legs bellow the knee were digitally removed in post production. For some scenes they may have used a double that was also a double amputee, but given how far special effects have come since then, and the level of action required, I doubt this is the case.

[image]

Comment: Note too that most shots of her did not show her blade-feet-prosthetics. Most shots framed her from the knee up, waist up, or shoulders up. In those shots no visual special effects were required, but the sound editor would need to include the unusual sound of her prosthetics touching the floor as she walked, in order to keep up the illusion for the audience.

Comment: Very true, and likely done to cut down on the amount of special effects shots that would be needed, likely to allow more time and money to be devoted to the action sequences which would require tons of work to look and feel right.

Comment: You're exactly right - they used green stockings with reflective dots to allow for post dimensioning to help with the animation plus also used computer controller cameras so that they could get a matching 'background-only' plate as the metal lets were inherently thinner than the actresses.

Comment: You can see the chroma socks in one of the [videos here](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/kingsman-not-so-secret-effects/).

Comment: I love this actor, but I can never remember his name. Sorry Gary, I'll always refer to you as "Lieutenant Dan".

Comment: How do I accomplish this effect by myself in Final Cut Pro or Premiere?

Answer (score 2):

The actress (Sofia Boutella) did do all the scenes shot, but in blue leggings. Later the special effects team put the prosthetic rapier (like) legs to finish off the shots.

Comment: What value does it adds to existing answer?